# C++ Data Strutures Queue: Find the largest element in the queue using for loop

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I need to find the largest element in an unsorted queue, remove it and store it in an auxiliary queue, then place it back as the first element in the main queue, WITHOUT using the standard queue functions from C++.

I tried to use a `for` loop to go through the queue and search for the largest element, but it didn't work. Any suggestion on how to do it properly?

```
//The queue was created as a class as follows:

class Queue{
  private:
    int arrayqueue[size];
    int start, end, counter;
  public:
    Queue();
    bool empty();
    bool full();
    bool insert(int item);
    bool remove();
    bool front(int &item);
    int counter_size();
    void copy(Queue &F);
    bool equal(Queue &F);
    void print();
    int largest_value(Queue &F,int n);
};

Queue::Queue(){
  counter = 0;
  start = 0;
  end = size -1;
}
```

This is the function I tried to build to find the largest element in the queue and store in the auxiliary queue:

```
//Create an auxiliary queue
//Find the largest element in the main queue, then remove it and insert it in the aux queue

int Queue::largest_value(Queue &F,int n){
  //int *Queue;
  // n is the size of the queue
  Queue aux; 
  int largest = Queue[0];
  for(int i = 1;i <n; i++) {
    if(largest < Queue[i])
      largest = Queue[i];
  }
  F.remove();
  aux.insert(largest);
  return largest;
}
```

Function to verify if it's empty:

```
bool Queue::empty(){
  if(counter == 0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

The function to remove elements:

```
bool Queue::remove(){
  if(empty()==true)
    return false;
  if(start==size-1)
    start = 0;
  else
    start++;
  counter--;
  return true;

}
```

Comment: Why does `largest_value()` take a `Queue` as input? Is `Queue[i]` is supposed to be `F[i]`? And if the queue being searched is empty, then accessing `Queue[0]` will be out of bounds. Why not search the array in `this` instead? And why is the loop `remove()`ing every element in `F`?  And `aux` is a local variable, it will be cleared when `largest_value()` exits, so what is the point of having it?

Comment: I think Queue[0] should be F[i], and Queue[i] should be F[i], I tried it but didnt work as well. In Queue aux , I'm declaring a new object from Queue which is the auxiliary queue.

Comment: Why would `F.remove()` know which element to remove?

Comment: @AngryDog but why is the `aux` queue INSIDE the `remove()` function?

Comment: The aux queue isn't inside of the remove function. In Queue aux , I'm declaring a new object from Queue inside of the largest_value() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```cpp
class Queue{
  private:
    int arrayqueue[size];
    int ... counter;
  public:
    ...
    bool remove_largest_value(int &value);
};

...

bool Queue::remove_largest_value(int &value) {
  if (counter == 0)
    return false;

  int largest = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < counter; ++i) {
    if (arrayqueue[largest] < arrayqueue[i])
      largest = i;
  }

  value = arrayqueue[largest];

  for(int i = largest + 1; i < counter; ++i) {
    arrayqueue[i-1] = arrayqueue[i];
  }
  --counter;

  return true;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Queue main;
// populate main as needed...

Queue aux; 
int item;

if (main.remove_largest_value(item))
{
  aux.insert(item);
  ...
  main.insert(item);
}
```

Comment: It worked but I think it's missing something. For example, for testing: Original queue for testing (Can be any values)
Main = 4 9 45 7

After removing largest
Main = 4 9 7 7
Aux = 45

Comment: @AngryDog It is not missing anything. You are just not taking into account that the 4th element in the array is no longer valid after the the 3rd element is "removed".  Since the array can't physically be resized, the value in the 4th slot is simply copied to the 3rd slot and the 4th slot retains its value, but the `counter` is decremented to ignore the 4th slot.

Comment: got it ! It worked now. I just called the remove function to remove the duplicate.  Like this if (q1.remove_largest_value(item))
{
  aux.insert(item);  
  q1.insert(item);  
  q1.remove();  
  cout<<"Main Queue";  
  q1.print();  
  cout<<"\n";  
  cout<<"Aux Queue";  
  aux.print();  
}

Comment: @AngryDog why are you calling `remove()` after `remove_largest_value()`? That implies your class may have some bigger design problems you need to work out.

Comment: I called the remove function to remove the duplicate in the main queue after remove the largest. It might not be the best practice but it's working.

Comment: @AngryDog the duplicate is only in physical memory, it should not be considered as still being "in" the queue. So again, if your class still "sees" the duplicate "in" the queue after `remove_largest_value()` was supposed to "remove" it from the queue, then your class design is buggy. I assumed the `counter` would handle that, but clearly your class relies on something else instead. So whatever logic `remove()` normally uses to make sure an item is actually removed from the queue (which you haven't shown) needs to be applied to `remove_largest_value()` as well when it removes the item it found.